# java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I got below exception when starting springboot application, when I implement aspect for testcontroller

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'testController' defined in file
>   [build\classes\java\main\com\nijil\fetch\service\identity\TestController.class]:
>   **Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP
>   exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable
>   to load cache item**

**Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 9**
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/nijil/fetch/service/identity/TestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a04bb642.()V @9: athrow
  Reason:
    Current frame's flags are not assignable to stack map frame's.

Comment: check the version of the libraries you're using.

Comment: have you been able to solve your problem? since I am facing the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure this is exact answer, but in my case this was the solution.

I was trying some AOP functions by using aspect4j and I had added spring-aop dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

to pom file and the application is working fine through STS, But when I'm going to deploy to the server above exception was came.

So finally I removed the above 'spring-aop' dependency from the pom and all went fine without any error or exceptions in running the applications as a jar.

I think there will be some incompatibilities with spring-aop version 5.0.1.RELEASE with the spring boot version 2.3.0.RELEASE (in my situation).