# Stack map does not match the one at exception handler - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-11

My SpringBoot app is returning the error listed below. Spring BootRun works fine. However when I start the application in Intellij or in Jenkins Pipeline , I see the error below. I am using JDK 11.What could be the potential issue that I may have to look at?

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 10
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/controller/MyController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e317dee.<init>(Lcom/service/MyService;)V @10: athrow
  Reason:
    Current frame's flags are not assignable to stack map frame's.
  Current Frame:
    bci: @0
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, 'com/service/MyService' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/RuntimeException' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @10
    flags: { }
    locals: { top, 'com/service/MyService' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Throwable' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a59 2bb7 015e b800 38b1 bfbb 004e 5a5f
    0000010: b700 51bf                              
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [0, 10] => handler: 10
    bci [0, 10] => handler: 10
    bci [0, 10] => handler: 11
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@10,{Top,Object[#352]},{Object[#76]})
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@11,Object[#76])
```

Comment: Cglib rewrites byte code. That might be the problem here.

Comment: Thanks @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. Could this potentially be caused any conflicting spring libraries?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am also having a very similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with the same problem.

Answer from [java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502419/java-lang-verifyerror-stack-map-does-not-match-the-one-at-exception-handle)
helped me to solve the problem.

In short I had a conflict in `spring-aop` dependency.
So:

1. I added plugin into `pom.xml` to find a conflict dependency:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <rules><dependencyConvergence/></rules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

2. run `mvn enforcer:enforce` and got

```
[WARNING] 
Dependency convergence error for org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.9 paths to dependency are:
+-com.syniverse.imn-webcore:soapfe:9.0.1
 +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.3
   +-org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.9
     +-org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.9

and
+-com.syniverse.imn-webcore:soapfe:9.0.1
 +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.5.8.RELEASE
   +-org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.3.RELEASE
     +-org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.9.RELEASE
```

Here are two different version - 4.3.9 and 5.3.9.

3. Added dependency with strict version 5.3.9 and it helped

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```